# Error when trying to initialize a consumer with the librdkafka-dev 1.8.0-1build1 library in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: c, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, librdkafka

I am trying to initialize a kafka consumer (C language) with the librdkafka-dev 1.8.0-1build1 library in Kubuntu 22.04. The problem is that I am getting an error when running the following line:

```
rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_CONSUMER, conf, errstr, sizeof(errstr));
```

The error is the following:

```
rd.h:148: rd_strdup: Assertion `n' failed.
```

Please, could you tell me if you have had a similar experience or any possible solution to the problem?

I have tried initializing it with the basic configurations and I always get the same error. I've even tried initializing a producer and the same thing happens.

However, when I run the same process on Ubuntu 16.04 with librdkafka-dev_0.8.6-1.1, it initializes the consumer fine.

What am I missing here?